# How to change state to awaiting_review always after update object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, state-machine

I have following state machine in app:

```
class Cv < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Workflow
  workflow do
    state :new do
      event :submit, :transitions_to => :awaiting_review
    end
    state :awaiting_review do
      event :review, :transitions_to => :being_reviewed
    end
    state :being_reviewed do
      event :accept, :transitions_to => :accepted
      event :reject, :transitions_to => :rejected
    end
    state :accepted
    state :rejected
  end

  def submit
    halt unless valid?
  end
end

# cvs_controller.rb
def update
  @cv = Cv.find(params[:id])
  if @cv.update_attributes(params[:cv])
    # @cv.back_to_review!
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

I would like move state to `awaiting_review` always after I update object.

So should I add in each state block `event :back_to_review!, :transitions_to => :awaiting_reviewed` ??

I am using this gem: https://github.com/geekq/workflow

Comment: do you use ActiveRecord?

Comment: Yes, I do. This is Rails app.

Comment: maybe you should define AR after_update callback an call event awaiting_review

Comment: which version of rails are you using?

Comment: then you need to define your custom after_update

Comment: but then when I change state ex: in show action ``review!`` it doesn't change state to ``being_reviewed`` because trigger ``after_update`` callback and change state back to ``awaiting_reviewed``

Comment: Then you need to track some particular attribute. On update of particular attribute you change the state. Can you tell me which attribute changes you want to track?

Comment: I want to track all attributes except state

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

**Edit**: As per your comment

```
 before_save do |w| 
     w.transition_to_awaiting_review if w.changes['attr_name']
 end

 event :transtion_to_awaiting_review do
    transition all => :awaiting_review
 end
```

This will only update when particular attributes of your model changes.

Comment: Hmm, I receive error: ``NoMethodError: undefined method `event' for #<Class:0x007f828edb6bc8>``

Comment: where did you put event method? It needs to be in state machine.

Comment: It seems that you're using some other state machine gem - Workflow does not support this syntax and does not allow transition from all to any other state